# Does everything on meta.stackoverflow.com apply to Seasoned Advice?

Tags: discussion, support

This [meta.stackoverflow question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92177/is-this-site-the-meta-site-for-all-of-the-stack-exchange-network-as-well-as-the/92178#92178) says it does, but it's a bit old. Is this still the case? Should we ask non-cooking-specific meta questions here or there?

Comment: Are you sure you're not fishing for meta cooking rep by answering your own question?  :)

Answer (score 5):

Much of what's on meta.stackoverflow applies here, but not necessarily all of it. Communities of individual sites can make their own decisions. A lot of meta discussion is at least a little subjective, and since it's all about making the sites work well, it does also depend on the kinds of things that are asked and answered on the site. While general principles apply across all StackExchange sites, they're not all exactly the same, and that's why we have site metas.

If you're looking to *ask* a meta question, you can absolutely post it here, whether or not it would apply to other sites.

If you're looking for an answer to a meta question, or trying find support for a meta answer you're writing, you should probably search here first to see what the Seasoned Advice community thinks, but it's of course likely that it hasn't been answered here but has on meta.stackoverflow, so often helpful information can be found there.

If you find conflicting information between our site meta and the StackOverflow meta, the opinions (and votes) here should take precedence.

There's *nothing* on Seasoned Advice that would guide a user to meta.stackoverflow.com; the meta link at the top points to Seasoned Advice meta, and the faq here simply say "Any question relevant to our community is welcome here." and do not link to meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: And to take this a step further, if someone asks a question about a site feature that's already been answered on MSO, it's perfectly fine (and encouraged) to answer here and include a link to the MSO answer for additional reading if needed.